# update a subfield with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a Node.js mongoose schema that looks like this:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var playersSchema = new Schema({
    login: String, 
    pwd: String,
    game: {
        lat: Number,
        lon: Number,
        speed: Number,
        money: Number
    }
});
```

I want to update only the game.money field of a given element. How can I do that with `findByIdAndUpdate` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB supports ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) for specifying fields in sub-documents. The same principle applies to either a plain object or an array of objects:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{ "$set": { "game.money" },function(err,doc) {

});
```

The [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator also only updates the specified field or fields without affecting the rest of the document and overwriting the full content.

Also see other [field update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) such as [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to increment an existing number, either up or down.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it, it seems there are unclosed brackets, besides { "game.money" } is not a valid object. Does this really work?